# Java, наследование, методы, generics

Tags: java, spring, ооп, generics, implementation

У нас есть интерфейс сущности `EntityI` и его реализация `Entity`.

Так же имеется интерфейс `SetupProviderI`, у которого есть метод `M1` возвращающий сущность `EntityI`, и реализация `SetupProvider`, у которого метод `М1` возвращает `Entity`.

Все работает, что логично (мы можем использовать интерфейс в виде возвращаемой сущности и возвращать его реализации).

А теперь я создаю в интерфейсе другой метод `М2`, который будет возвращать `List<EntityI>`, но в реализации буду возвращать `List<Entity>`. И здесь уже у нас ошибка, не дает.

*Получается мы можем вернуть интерфейс и его имплементаторов, но это касается только одного объекта, а для коллекций нам нужно использовать **generics**, верно?*

Благодарю

Comment: Покажите код и сообщение об ошибке. Из того, что вы описали словами, все должно работать. Но тут есть несколько моментов, которые можно трактовать по разному. Так что нужен код, чтоб не было разночтений и догадок.

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема с дженериками. Дело в том, что в джаве дженерики не ковариантны (в отличии, кстати, от массивов).
То есть вместо `List<EntityI>` вы можете вернуть `ArrayList<EntityI>`, но вы не можете вернуть `List<Entity>`. Тип дженерика менять нельзя, полиморфизм работает только по коллекции (List <- ArrayList, например).